# How can I dynamically reference a control in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, controls, picturebox

I'm trying to select a control based on setting a variable equal to that control like so:

```
selectedBox = sender
```

For reference this is how I declare selectedBox:

```
Dim selectedBox As PictureBox
```

What I was hoping to do was something like this:

```
If selectedBox = picbox then
...
```

Where picbox is a picturebox passed to the function.

However this doesn't work due to:

```
Operator '=' is not defined for types 'PictureBox' and 'PictureBox'
```

So what can I do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Is` like so:

```
If selectedBox Is picbox Then
```